# JavaScript - Waiting for asynchronus functions in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have a JS file with indexedDB functions, like this:

```
// Get all object stores from IndexedDB
mydb.indexedDB.getObjStores = function() {
  var db = mydb.indexedDB.db;
  return db.objectStoreNames;
};
```

I call this function from another JS file, where I need the names of the object stores to do something with them like populate a combo:

```
function doSomething(){
  var arr = mydb.indexedDB.getObjStores();
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    document.getElementById('mycombo').options[i] = new Option (arr[i], i);
  }
}
```

Depending on the browser, the combo is empty, although I can get the lenght of the array (weird). I think the problem is that asynchronus thing that is killing me... I thought that using something like addEventListener was a good idea ([When can I tell that I have opened a connection in indexedDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641751/indexeddb-best-method-to-wait-for-database-to-open-in-function-in-javascript)), but this indexedDB call has no onsuccess event. It works fine with Chrome and Firefox, but not in a PDA browser e.g.
How can I wait for this? Is that the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: so is `arr[0]` undefined or is `arr` undefined?

Comment: arr[0] is undefined... as I said, I can get the length of arr.
Thank you.

Comment: You're right. What does it say when you do `console.dir(arr)`?

Comment: I cannot use console to "debug" in the PDA which is the browser with the problems :S It has no cosole. That's part of my problem, I'm not sure what is happening. In Chrome and Firefox i get the array as I expected.

Comment: it has alert, right? Or write a debug function that appends text in a (scrollable) absolute-position div..

Comment: The value is undefined too.

Comment: arr is undefined but its length isnt? :O Do you happen to have a link availeble?

Comment: Array lenght is 1, as it should be... it's very strange

Comment: does a PDA even have an indexedDB? isnt it something like that?

Comment: IndexedDB works well, I know because I can check the object stores and the values and everything is ok. But something strange happens with I'm getting the names of teh object stores in my indexedDB.

Comment: I'm (obviously) not sure what the problem is, but I think that we/I miss out on code to determine the actual cause..

Comment: Not all IndexedDB API support objectStoreNames. So check it first.

Comment: Problem solved. The definition of objectStoreNames given by this browser was different from what I expected. It's an object with arrays which stores a bunch of properties such as a list of object stores. I was retrieving data that does not exist (undefined).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The indexedDB specification in this browser is a little bit different: getObjStores() returns an object with some arrays, one of them the list of object stores. So I was retrieving unexisting data, because I was expecting a DOMStringList. An "stupid" error in a very particular case. Thank you.